# Access locally hosted server in MAC via Internet Explorer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, internet-explorer, browser, localhost

I need to hit my localhost url from Internet Explorer for testing purpose. My Rails application is hosted locally.

However, I need to test this local application in Internet Explorer browser. Is there any way to emulate IE in Mac?

I can not use virtual desktops as I fail to access localhost, even via Mac's IPv4. This is possibly because there are multiple redirections needed, all of which are defined in /etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, if you need to use Internet Explorer on Mac, it’s probably for testing purposes, to see how certain websites or web apps perform, or to access websites that require you to use IE (yes, those still exist).

Both of those use cases could be easily performed by Safari. To use Internet Explorer with Safari, you just need to turn on developer tools:

(1) In Safari, go to Preferences > Advanced

(2) Check “Show Develop menu in menu bar”

[image]

Now you can access developer tools directly from Safari, which let you inspect websites, empty caches, and most importantly simulate a variety of other browsers right through the Safari app. To use Microsoft Edge or Internet Explorer on Mac:

(1) Go to the Develop menu in Safari’s menu bar

(2) Navigate to User Agent and select the browser you’re looking for, whether it’s Microsoft Edge, any of the Internet Explorer versions, Google Chrome, Firefox, etc.

(3) The website you’re on will be automatically refreshed to reflect the browser of your choice. Just don’t forget to switch back!

[image]

The User Agent option in Safari should cover nearly all reasons for using Internet Explorer on Mac.

Reference:

[Simulate Internet Explorer on Mac with Safari](https://setapp.com/how-to/use-internet-explorer-for-mac)

Comment: Thanks. I did try that already and my issue in IE is not replicated using this mode in Safari.

Comment: There is no any official way provided by Microsoft to install IE on MAC so it is advisable to install any Windows OS in virtual machine and do your test there.